# How to duplicate the rows of a table based on count

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a frequency table like this in an Oracle database where N is the number of each occurrence:

```
weight | N
12     | 3
34     | 2
56     | 1
```

Is it possible to multiply the number of each row by the number of occurences to get a table like this:

```
weight | N
12     | 1
12     | 1
12     | 1
34     | 1
34     | 1
56     | 1
```

Thank you,

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use number generator, recursive query, xmltable. Many options. For example:

```
with t as (select weight, '1 to '||n list from frequency)
select weight, 1 from t, xmltable(list)
```

or

```
with r(weight, n) as (select weight, n from frequency union all
                      select weight, n-1 from r where n-1 > 0)
select weight, 1 from r order by weight
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cfe761639786e0f3522b21ae02f0a8e7)</sup>**

Answer (score 0):

One simple method is a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select weight, n
      from t
      union all 
      select weight, n - 1
      from t
      where n > 1
     )
select weight, 1 as n
from cte;
```

Note that although recursive CTEs are part of the standard, there are variations in the syntax, so your database might be a little different.

EDIT:

In older versions of Oracle, you can generate the numbers you need and then generate the data:

```
with n as (select level as n
           from (select max(n) as n from t) n
           connect by level <= n
          )
select t.weight, 1 as n
from t join
     n
     on n.n <= t.n;
```

New versions of Oracle support recursive CTEs.

Comment: Thank you for your input but it is not working (i.e each row is not multiplied by the number of occurences). I am not sure what is being done actually. Is there an other way ?